# Client Document Management System - Joomla, Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, joomla

Does anyone know of a good open source client document management system?

Possibly using Joomla or Wordpress?

I need to be able to allow different clients to log into the website to download their documents and upload their documents?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you taken a look at WordPress's Document Revisions?

http://ben.balter.com/2011/08/29/wp-document-revisions-document-management-version-control-wordpress/

WP Document Revisions is essentially three things:

1. A document management system (DMS), to track, store, and organize
   files of any format,
2. A collaboration tool to empower teams to collaboratively draft, edit, and refine documents, and
3. A file hosting solution to publish and securely deliver files to a team, to
   clients, or to the public

Comment: I'll second this one.  Ben's plugin is pretty awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if they had come with a sollution like that in wordpress (a couple of months ago they were asking for that in the forums), but this might work for you (some people have been using this instead): http://lesterchan.net/portfolio/programming/php/#wp-downloadmanager

Answer (score 0):

There are several document repository components for Joomla in this category: http://extensions.joomla.org/category/directory-a-documentation/downloads